# Boolean difference removing wrong geometry

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to subtract a shallow bowl-like shape from this basic trough. The subtraction should only serve to round out the top.
[image: Trough to be edited]

When I enable the modifier it deletes the internal geometry of the trough even though none of it is intersecting with the cutter.

[image]

[image: Trough with boolean enabled and backface culling enabled to show the absence of internal geometry]

I have enabled backface culling to show the removal of the internal geometry.

I have checked normals, manifoldness, and made sure that I don't have any colinear plains. any help would be appreciated.

Edit: added picture of the cutter.

Comment: Boolean modifiers tend to be very finicky. It looks like you can avoid using a boolean operator by deleting the top face of the trough and adding a solidify modifier instead.

Comment: The geometry is already made via solidify modifier. Also the boolean is to make it fit snugly against another modeled part. This is meant to be 3d printed

Comment: Oh wait a moment, can you clarify what "rounding the top" refers to? Can you add a screenshot of the cutting object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding that changing the offset on my solidify modifier fixed the problem. I am still not sure why this happened but that is my fix.